# Explanation behind MsSQL Select Queries

Tags: sql-server

`Select count(*); -- returns 1`
`Select $; -- returns 0.00`

Would it be possible for anyone to explain the reason behind these MsSQL query results ?

Comment: on sql 2012 first statement produces an error and second statement returns 0.00. which version of sql server are you using? which compatilibility level is the db you are running the query against?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 and the compatibility level is 100 for the database I am using. And, I am very sorry, but now, I have corrected my question.

Comment: instead of `*` if you use any other special char like `!@#%^&*` that will also giving a same error `$` behave like money

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 0.00 with $ since SQL Server is converting it into a `money` data type. With `*` there is no such conversion happening and hence it results in an error.

See the [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172602%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> When converting to money or smallmoney, integers are assumed to be
>   monetary units. For example, the integer value of 4 is converted to
>   the money equivalent of 4 dollars (for us_english, the default
>   language). Numbers to the right of the decimal in floating-point
>   values are rounded to four decimal places for money values.
>   Expressions of data types char or varchar that are being converted to
>   an integer data type must consist only of digits and an optional plus
>   or minus sign (+ or -). Leading blanks are ignored. **Expressions of
>   data types char or varchar converted to money can also include an
>   optional decimal point and leading dollar sign ($).**

Comment: Sorry, it was count( * ) instead of ( * ).

Comment: @bigyanshr:- Then that is different. count(*). Check the MSDN for count() `a) If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality of T.`

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. But, I am having trouble in identifying what T is here for the query select count(*);